# Different result from same command in powershell 3.0

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

Given that `Get-ChildItem -Path *.exe` will show all the executables in the current directory, why doesn't `Get-ChildItem -File -Include *.exe` return the same result? Both commands are executed in the same directory, first command (with -Path) returns a list of executables but the second command (with -File) doesn't. (`gci -File`  will list everything including the exe)

```
Get-ChildItem -File | gm  #=> FileInfo
Get-ChildItem *.* | gm    #=> DirectoryInfo and FileInfo
```

All the commands bellow return objects of type FileInfo

```
Get-ChildItem -File
Get-ChildItem *.* -Include *.exe
Get-ChildItem -Path *.exe
```

But mixing -File and -Include/-Exclude returns nothing, even though the -include is looking for a filetype:

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Include *.exe    #=> Returns nothing
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: alexander are you sure you have any exe file in path you query for exe file do you test `gci -filter -include *.exe -Recurse ` that seeking exe file in all directory and subdirectory

Comment: Yes I have exe in path. gci -Path *.exe returns the list of them. Running gci -File -Recurse -Include *.exe does so too, but it includes all the exes in the sub directory too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From TechNet:

> The Include parameter is effective only when the command includes the
>   Recurse parameter or the path leads to the contents of a directory,
>   such as C:\Windows*, where the wildcard character specifies the
>   contents of the C:\Windows directory.

In other words, when you use the Include parameter, it does not automatically consider all files and directories unless you use the Path or the Recurse parameters.  Notice, that when just using the Path parameter, you must include a wildcard to force it to consider the file and directory results underneath that path.  I cannot think of why this is.

To get your examples to work, you would use one of the following (I'm dropping the File parameter because it seems redundant):

```
Get-ChildItem -Path * -Include *.exe
Get-ChildItem -Include *.exe -Recurse
```

The gist of my answer to your question is an opinion tho - from what I've seen the Include parameter should be removed - or its behavior repaired to match the default behavior of the Get-ChildItem cmdlet when used without parameters.  There may be a good explanation to why it works this way, but I'm unaware of this.

If you drop the Include parameter from your examples, the behavior/results make more sense (to me):

```
Get-ChildItem -Path *.exe
```

In this case, we would only need the Exclude parameter to effectively cover all filtering requirements. Something like:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path *.exe -Exclude *system*
```